# ManagedBean doesn't declare a public no-argument constructor

Tags: jsf, constructor, managed-bean

I am using PrimeFaces 5.0 and want to create `<p:treeTable>` inside the popup box after click event but its showing following error

> Unable to create managed bean `popupTreeTableManagedBean`. The following
>   problems were found: - Managed bean class
>   `beans.PopupTreeTableManagedBean` for managed bean
>   `popupTreeTableManagedBean` doesn't declare a public no-argument
>   constructor. - Managed bean class `beans.PopupTreeTableManagedBean` for
>   managed bean `popupTreeTableManagedBean` doesn't declare a public
>   no-argument constructor.

Here are my code snippets

index.xhtml:

```
<p:dialog header="" widgetVar="dlg1" minHeight="200">
    <p:treeTable value="#{popupTreeTableManagedBean.root}" var="node" style="" >
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{node.name}"></h:outputText>
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Value</f:facet>
            <h:inputText value="#{node.value}" style="border-style: hidden;"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:treeTable>
</p:dialog>
```

PopupTreeTableManagedBean.java

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class PopupTreeTableManagedBean {

    private TreeNode root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root Node", null);
    List<String> selectedParams;
    TreeNode scanParamsRoot = null;

    PopupTreeTableManagedBean() {
        selectedParams = GenrateScanList.getParamList();
        createRootAndLeafNodes();
    }

    private TreeNode createRootAndLeafNodes() {
        TreeNode scanSubRoot = null;
        int size = selectedParams.size();
        TreeNode scanRoot = new DefaultTreeNode(new Document("scanParams", ""), this.root);
        scanSubRoot = new DefaultTreeNode(new Document("Sub Root", ""), scanRoot);

        Document relationshipValue = new Document("Hi", "");
        TreeNode documentss06 = new DefaultTreeNode(relationshipValue, scanSubRoot);
        return root;
    }

    private DefaultTreeNode getTreeNodeObject() {
        return new DefaultTreeNode();
    }

    private Document getDocumentObject() {
        return new Document(null, null);
    }

    public TreeNode getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void setRoot(TreeNode root) {
        this.root = root;
    }
}
```

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message says you need a `public` constructor, but your constructor is **package private**. Adding the `public` keyword should help.

Comment: In addition this constructor should be replaced with `@PostConstruct` method.

Comment: Initialization in a bean constructor is perfectly legit unless it does not depend upon dependency injections.